# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromNativeSource' of undefined

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

```
import  imageSource from "tns-core-modules/image-source"; let x  = imageSource.fromNativeSource(bmp);
```

I have been trying to draw on an image using android.graphics canvas in nativescript-vue project and when i import image source i get this error. Please i am new to nativescript

Comment: Try `import * as imageSource from "tns-core-modules/image-source"; `

Answer (score 0):

Or if you use NS7+ you'll have to use @nativescript/core imports instead of the tns-core-modules.

Comment: Where can I find 'fromNativeSource', or something similar, in NS 8? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I think this answer will be useful.

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65548076/1698723) you will need to update your imports from `@nativescript/core`

```
import { ImageSource } from '@nativescript/core'
```

And to make a new image from a native source you will need to use the `ImageSource` constructor.

```
const image = new ImageSource(nativeSource);

// the old way is now deprecated
// const image = imageSourceModule.fromNativeSource(nativeSource);
```